# Star rate script doesn't work with static urls (RewriteRule)

Tags: php

have a problem with star rate script. It's working fine with dynamic urls, example:

/index.php?md=details&id2

but it doesn't work with same link but in static, example:

/ads/test-add-idn2.html

Example of rewrite rule:

> RewriteRule ^ads/(.*)-idn(.*).html$ index.php?md=details&id=$2
>   [L,NE]

Example "require" that is working with dynamic urls but not static:

> require('_star-rating.php'); // get the db connection info

How to call "_star-rating.php" to work with static urls?

With another rewrite rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the right information:

```
^ads/(.)-idn(.).html$
            ^^^ a dot can be any character, but only one
     ^^^ same here
```

You probably need something like:

```
^ads/([-\w]+)-idn(\d+)\.html$
```

- `[-\w]+` : one or more word characters or `-` signs
- `\d+` : one or more digits

**Edit:** Please note that this (a `.htaccess` file) only affects urls that get called via the web-browser / http. When you are using `include` or `require` in php, you are dealing with the local file-system and that has nothing to do with any `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I think the problem with star rate script is because it's called before ^ads/ . It shoud be after ads/ but don't have a clue how to do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Sela I did not answer the second part of your question initially, see my edit.

Comment: I change to RewriteRule ^ads/(.*)-idn([0-9]*)\.html$ index.php?md=details&id=$2 [L,NE] like Mike sugest (thanks mike) but is the same. Thanks for note Jeroen.

Answer (score 0):

Think your rule jsut isnt correct. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^ads/(.*?)-idn(\d+)\.html$ index.php?md=details&id=$2 [L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is not going to match.  If you are trying to capture everything in the URI before `-idn` and get the number after it, you would need to change your pattern like:

```
RewriteRule ^ads/(.*)-idn([0-9]*)\.html$ index.php?md=details&id=$2 [L,NE]
```

Note that we use the `*` to match the wildcard `.` for all text before `-idn`. We also use character class `[0-9]` to specify that we are interesting in 0 or more numbers after `-idn` and before literal `.` (which must be escaped so as not to be treated as wildcard `.`.